# How to extract data from regex expression in this instance?

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping

I am attempting to scrape ridernames from [this URL](https://dataride.uci.ch/Results/iframe/RankingDetails/119?disciplineId=8&groupId=48&momentId=39994&disciplineSeasonId=139&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=71)

Currently I'm struggling with my regex expression, as it works fine in matching the content (regex101), however I'm unsure how I take a matching regex expression and use it to extract the values that much.

When I scrape, I can alter findall to finditer to match with it (and receive a result), but I am unsure how I go from there, and get it repeatedly assigning returned values to the list

```
# import modules
import urllib.request
import urllib.parse
import re

# fake user agent for access
user_agent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 5.1; en-US; rv:1.9.0.7) Gecko/2009021910 Firefox/3.0.7'
headers={'User-Agent':user_agent,}

url = 'https://dataride.uci.ch/Results/iframe/RankingDetails/119?disciplineId=8&groupId=48&momentId=39994&disciplineSeasonId=139&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=71'
req = urllib.request.Request(url, None,headers)
resp = urllib.request.urlopen(req)
respData = resp.read()

riders = re.findall(r'(<a)\s+(href=\"/Results/iframe/RiderRankingDetails/)[0-9]+(\?rankingId=)[0-9]+(\&amp;groupId=)[0-9]+(\&amp;momentId=)[0-9]+(\&amp;baseRankingTypeId=)[0-9]+(\&amp;disciplineSeasonId=)[0-9]+(\&amp;disciplineId=)[0-9]+(\&amp;categoryId=)[0-9]+(\&amp;raceTypeId=)[0-9]+(\">)[A-Z]+\s+[A-Za-z]+(</a>),str(respData))
# The [A-Z]+\s+[A-Za-z] part contains the rider name that I wish to scrape

for name in riders:
    print(name)
```

`[A-Z]+\s+[A-Za-z]` in the regex expression should be returned to the list riders, so that then I may print every rider name.

Comment: Why you need regex if you can scrape the rider names directly based on the tag class?

Comment: Can you include a working version of your code? You have a SyntaxError and a TypeError.

Comment: Thats because it does not give an output as of yet, that's what I need help with, I certainly dont have a syntax error however. Where is the type error (nvm found it I think it was the 3rd parameter on findall, I forgot to paste it over onto stack overflow)? If I could just use tag class, what do I need to amend? I only know regex as that's what I've been instructed to use here.

Comment: The page is dynamically generated. You cannot download it with urllib. Consider using `selenium` or another headless browser.

Answer (score 0):

As @DYZ mentioned in comments the web page is dynamically generated, when you try to download it with urlib you will get a webpage like this:
[image: NonSenseWebpage]

but if you visit the same webpage via browser you will get all riders and ranks displayed because browsers execute java scripts which downloaders like urllib or requests don't do

[image: the webpage via browser]

you should seek another method if you need information from this site or you can try beautifulSoup if you just want to learn web scraping

Answer (score 0):

It's clear that the elements you want to capture are generated dynamically. Thus, you need `selenium`. From your description, you want to get the name of the riders. First, you have to download the [chromedriver](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads) which is match with the version of your chrome. Then try this code:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

browser = webdriver.Chrome(r'/path/chromedriver')  #refers to the path of your downloaded chromedriver

browser.get("https://dataride.uci.ch/Results/iframe/RankingDetails/119?disciplineId=8&groupId=48&momentId=39994&disciplineSeasonId=139&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=71")

post_elems = browser.find_elements_by_tag_name("a")

for post in post_elems[3:]:
    if post.text != '':
        print (post.text)
```

Output:

```
CORNEGLIANI Fabrizio
BACHMAIER Ernst
JAHODA Patrik
FRÜH Benjamin
SIMEONI Manolo
TUOR Alain
UBERTI Giuseppe
GOMIERO Andrea
PANTANO Dino
```

Answer (score 0):

You can mimic the POST request of the page which is faster than using a browser

```
import requests

headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Mozilla/5.0',
           'Referer' : 'https://dataride.uci.ch/Results/iframe/RankingDetails/119?disciplineId=8&groupId=48&momentId=39994&disciplineSeasonId=139&rankingTypeId=1&categoryId=22&raceTypeId=71'}
data = {

'rankingId' : 119,
'disciplineId' : 8,
'currentRankingTypeId' : 1,
'rankingTypeId' : 1,
'take' : 40,
'skip' : 0,
'page' : 1,
'pageSize' : 40,
'filter[filters][0][field]' : 'RaceTypeId',
'filter[filters][0][value]' : 71,
'filter[filters][1][field]' : 'CategoryId',
'filter[filters][1][value]' : 22,
'filter[filters][2][field]' : 'SeasonId',
'filter[filters][2][value]' : 139,
'filter[filters][4][value]' : 0 
}
r = requests.post('https://dataride.uci.ch/Results/iframe/ObjectRankings/', headers = headers, data = data).json()   
riders = [item['DisplayName'] for item in r['data']]
print(riders)
```

---

**Output:**

[image]